# Firestore transaction sequential creation of collections and updating of documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Enviroment: **nodejs**, **firebase-admin**, **firestore**.

Database scructure (**space**):
[image: space structure]

Database scructure (**user**):
[image]

Creating new space (example):

```
// init data
const userId = "someUserId";
// Create new space
const spaceRef = await db.collection("spaces").add({ name: "SomeName" });
// Get spaceId
spaceId = spaceRef.id;
// Get user Doc for upate their spaces
const userRef = await db.collection("users").doc(userId);
// Add "spaceId" to user spaces list
userRef.collection("spaces").doc(spaceId).set({ some: "data" });
// Create collection "members" in new space with "userId"
spaceRef.collection("members").doc(userId).set({role: "OWNER"})
```

**Question**: I want to execute this code inside single [runTransaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions), but as I see transactions support only one-time read and multiple update, this does not suit me, since I get the `spaceId` I need during the execution of the code.

**Why I want to use transaction**: In my data structure, the relationship between the created space and the presence of the ID of this space on the user is required. If we assume that an error occurred during the execution of this code, for example, the space was created, but this space was not added inside the user profile, then this will be a fatal problem in my database structure.

Similar to other databases, transactions solve this problem, but I can't figure out how to do it with firestore.

Maybe you know a better way to protect yourself from consistent data in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you don't need a Transaction for that, since you are not reading documents.

With `db.collection("users").doc(userId);` you are actually not reading a document, just calling "locally" the `doc()` method to create a `DocumentReference`. This method is not asynchronous, therefore you don't need to use `await`. To read the doc, you would use the asynchronous `get()` method.

---

So, using a [**batched write**](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/WriteBatch.html), which **atomically** commits all pending write operations to the database, will do the trick:

```
  const userId = 'someUserId';
  const userRef = db.collection('users').doc(userId);

  const spaceRef = firestore.collection('spaces').doc();
  const spaceId = spaceRef.id;

  const writeBatch = firestore.batch();
  writeBatch.set(spaceRef, { name: "SomeName" });
  writeBatch.set(userRef.collection("spaces").doc(spaceId), { some: "data" });
  writeBatch.set(spaceRef.collection("members").doc(userId), {role: "OWNER"});

  await writeBatch.commit();
```

You should include this code in a `try/catch` block and if the batch commit fails you will be able to handle this situation in the `catch` block, knowing that none of the write were committed.

Comment: hm, I mistakenly believed that only after the operation `.add ({name:" Some Name "})` with server response, I can get the ID of the newly created space. But it turns out, judging by your example, that the `.doc ()` function prepares a random `id` for earlier, without request to server at all, and already uses it when creating it.
The `.doc ()` function does not work as I expected :) Thanks.

Comment: "the `doc()` function prepares a random id for earlier, without request to server" => that’s exactly that!